# :autosave ignored on has_many relation -- what am I missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a pair of classes:

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  has_many :items, autosave: true
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :collection
end
```

From the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html):

> When :autosave is true all children is saved, no matter whether they are new records:

But when I update an `Item` and save its parent `Collection`, the `Item`'s upated attributes don't get saved:

```
 > c = Collection.first
 => #<Collection id: 1, name: "collection", created_at: "2012-07-23 00:00:10", updated_at: "2012-07-23 00:00:10"> 
 > i = c.items.first
 => #<Item id: 1, collection_id: 1, name: "item1", created_at: "2012-07-23 00:00:25", updated_at: "2012-07-23 00:00:25"> 
 > i.name = 'new name'
 => "new name" 
 > c.save
 => true 
 > Collection.first.items
 => [#<Item id: 1, collection_id: 1, name: "item1", created_at: "2012-07-23 00:00:25", updated_at: "2012-07-23 00:00:25">]
```

So, what am I missing?

I'm using Rails 3.2.5 and Ruby 1.9.2.

---

So I've done some digging about in the source of ActiveRecord.  We can get hold of `c`'s autosave assocations:

```
 > c.class.reflect_on_all_autosave_associations
 => [#<ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection:0x007fece57b3bd8 @macro=:has_many, @name=:items, @options={:autosave=>true, :extend=>[]}, @active_record=Collection(id: integer, name: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime), @plural_name="items", @collection=true, @class_name="Item", @klass=Item(id: integer, collection_id: integer, name: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime), @foreign_key="collection_id", @active_record_primary_key="id", @type=nil>]
```

I think this illustrates that the association has been set up for autosaving.

We can then get the instance of the association corresponding to `c`:

```
 > a = c.send :association_instance_get, :items
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::HasManyAssociation:0x007fece738e920 @target=[#<Item id: 1, collection_id: 1, name: "item1", created_at: "2012-07-23 00:00:25", updated_at: "2012-07-23 00:00:25">], @reflection=#<ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection:0x007fece57b3bd8 @macro=:has_many, @name=:items, @options={:autosave=>true, :extend=>[]}, @active_record=Collection(id: integer, name: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime), @plural_name="items", @collection=true, @class_name="Item", @klass=Item(id: integer, collection_id: integer, name: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime), @foreign_key="collection_id", @active_record_primary_key="id", @type=nil>, @owner=#<Collection id: 1, name: "collection", created_at: "2012-07-23 00:00:10", updated_at: "2012-07-23 00:00:10">, @updated=false, @loaded=true, @association_scope=[#<Item id: 1, collection_id: 1, name: "item1", created_at: "2012-07-23 00:00:25", updated_at: "2012-07-23 00:00:25">], @proxy=[#<Item id: 1, collection_id: 1, name: "item1", created_at: "2012-07-23 00:00:25", updated_at: "2012-07-23 00:00:25">], @stale_state=nil>
```

We can then find the actual objects that are associated via this association:

```
 > a.target
 => [#<Item id: 1, collection_id: 1, name: "item1", created_at: "2012-07-23 00:00:25", updated_at: "2012-07-23 00:00:25">]
```

The object found here does not have update that I'd made earlier.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem here is the line

```
 i = c.items.first
```

This line pulls the correct item from the database, but *doesn't* attach it to the collection c. It is a distinct ruby object from the object

```
i = c.items[0]
```

If you replace the first line with the second your example will work.

Comment: Normally it basically is.  This difference is caused by Rails helpfully turning #first into SQL predicates.  You can see Ruby #first's C source here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-first and Ralis's relation here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f244d8f53279efd755e7299418b408641baedc9c/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L128